# Single NPN Transistor Audio Preamp

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

I try to make a little project for school.I used the following schema to create an audio amplifier.

For the circuit I used:

C1:104j63 capacitor (1uF)

C2:103j (0,1uF)

My problem is that the sound is lower than direct input.

I changed both capacitors with a 104 and the sound was same as the input but more distorsioned.

PS:The transistor is connected correctly.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that circuit?

Comment: What is the purpose of R1?

Comment: R1 may power an electret microphone.  So make sure the microphone polarity is also correct.

Comment: What is your load? An 8-ohm speaker? Or a 10Mohm oscilloscope? If it's a speaker, the 10k R3 is your culprit.

Comment: @MattYoung http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=327

Comment: To be perfectly honest, as far as amplifiers are concerned, it's garbage.

Comment: I remember this schematic.I posted it in a question and also built it physically.Note that the transistor will be very weak and useless,much as Matt Young states.I had to put my ear tightly on the speaker to hear the outputed sound.Why all this?Because this is a PREAMP not an amplifier.It is supposed to boost very low signals so they can drive an amplifier stage.You might want to modify it if you want it to work.

Comment: But it's good garbage, Matt, and probably works a lot better than a lot of rank beginner's first attempts.  It's a start.  I do question the input levels from an audio player, though.

Comment: That circuit is not meant to power a speaker but amplify the few mV from a electret to line level (i.e. to about 1V). For a single-transistor amp that can comfortably power a speaker look at [this schematic](http://anrieff.net/abs/i/class-a-1.png) and accompanying [video/audio demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfEfxXIUYgE). Basically you need a power transistor and much lower resistor values. IF you want to go from electret directly to speaker, that's a pretty tall order for a single transistor amp. I suggest you use two stages.

Comment: also, with no emitter resistor, i am not sure how the transistor will bias.  it could be saturated if the \$\beta\$ is high.  or it could be in cutoff if the \$\beta\$ is low.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I don't think it can saturate. As long as the base collector junction is reverse biased (or zero), it will not be in saturation. But if the base collector junction is forward-biased, then the  base current would have to be negative, which is impossible in this circuit. So it will always bias to a non-saturated operating point.

Comment: certainly with sufficient base current, a BJT will saturate.  but i see what you mean.  if \$V_\text{cb}\$ gets small enough, the base current is small.  it can still bias close to saturation.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I am not disputing the phenomenon of saturation itself. What I am saying is that in this circuit, I don't see how the transistor could ever be biased into saturation. As long as Vcb is >= 0, the transistor will not be saturated. I don't see how Vcb could ever be negative in this circuit. The way it is biased guarantees that the collector will always be at a slighly higher voltage than the base. It is similar to a diode connected configuration, except with an extra 10k between base and collector.

Comment: i changed my position to saying that it gets **close to saturation**.  and with \$V_\text{ce}\$ only 0.05 volts more than  \$V_\text{be}\$ when  \$\beta\$=1000, i would say that is **damn** close.  even when   \$\beta\$=100, there's less than a volt left for \$V_\text{cb}\$ .  that's not very well biased when \$V_\text{cc}\$=5v.

Answer (score 1):

Simulation shows that this will work just fine - as long as you use it as a preamp, and do not try to drive a speaker. Driving a 10k load it will produce about a gain of 60. Driving an 8-ohm speaker it will have a gain of about 1/8.

So don't try to drive a speaker with it, OK?

Comment: for what range of transistor \$\beta\$ does this simulation work?  lacking an emitter resistor (it could be bypassed with an electrolytic cap if you don't want it to kill the amplifier gain), i am not sure how you can be sure it biases up correctly.

Comment: and the OP can put in another transistor (or two as darlingtons) in the back end in voltage-follower mode, if they want to drive a speaker.

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson - I use TINA. The 2N3904 model has a default beta of 679, and results varied a few percent for a range of 100 to 1000.

Comment: a \$ 100 \le \beta \le 1000 \$ and no emitter resistor?  i use pen and paper and i will just go check on where that Q point ends up.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - Keep in mind that I'm assuming a 1 mV input.

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson - Beta range of 100 to 1000 gives DC operating point of 1.35 to 1.04 volts.

Comment: what's \$V_\text{cc}\$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson - 5 volts.

Comment: if \$\beta\$=100 then \$V_\text{ce}\$=1v.  if \$\beta\$=1000 then \$V_\text{ce}\$=0.65v .  neither case is well biased.  for \$V_\text{cc}\$=5v, a good bias might be \$V_\text{ce}\$=2.5v .  this is assuming \$V_\text{be}\$=0.6v .