# Using 2N3904 NPN for audio amplification

Tags: esp8266, audio

I use a great library [ESP8266Audio](https://github.com/earlephilhower/ESP8266Audio) for play audio using ESP8266. As the author explained we can use 2n3904 for audio amplification as follow:

```
                            2N3904 (NPN)
                            +---------+
                            |         |     +-|
                            | E  B  C |    / S|
                            +-|--|--|-+    | P|
                              |  |  +------+ E|
                              |  |         | A|
ESP8266-GND ------------------+  |  +------+ K| 
                                 |  |      | E|
ESP8266-I2SOUT (Rx) -------------+  |      \ R|
                                    |       +-|
USB 5V -----------------------------+
```

It works but still, the volume is not acceptable with 0.5W 8Ω speaker. I also tested with some other speaker, same result. With normal amplifier is much louder.
I'm not very good at electronic. Is there any way to add another transistor to make it louder, having a simple low pass filter behind would be awesome too. Thanks

Comment: Interesting though this question is, this seems to me a purely electronics question: "How to amplify sound with a single 2N3904 transistor such that it can drive a loudspeaker" and thus is better suited to Electronics Stack Exchange. Please remain seated while your question is redirected. :)

Comment: Actually the [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) audio power amplifier would be a better choice if you want to drive a speaker with simple circuit with very few components. You can even buy a pre-built module from sparkfun. The 2N3904 is just a bare NPN transistor, without the necessary biasing circuitry. You could build a common-emitter pre-amplifier around a 2N3904, but it needs more support components, and still won't be able to drive a speaker directly.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351819/audio-amplifier-op-amp-without-feedback

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207609/single-npn-transistor-audio-preamp?rq=1